# What kind of wire is the white neutral wire and where can I get it?

Tags: switch

With my carror smart fan, it came with a switch and the instructions say that the white neutral wire is supplied, but I don't have it and unable to locate it:

[image]

With that being said, where exactly can I get a replacement "white neutral wire"? I'm not an electrician so this is a bit awkward for me, but I have swapped out standard light switches for about 30 lutron switches thus far with no issues. This is the first time I've run into a snag where I'm unable to find a cable to complete the instructions.

As I've performed more and more research, I've only run into more confusion about the different kinds of wires (14/2, 14/3, solid wires, etc.). I also don't know where I can find something similar that is only 3-4" instead of 250+ ft long and expensive.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Alternatively, can I just take one of the white neutral wires from the cap (in the wallbox) and connect it to the switch?

Comment: If you don't have the supplied white neutral wire, just return the switch, it is defective.

Comment: Without insulting you, the first number is the wire size. The smaller the number the ticker the wire. 14/2 mens 14 gauge and 2 wires. 14 gauge is good for up to 15 amp circuit (fan+Light). Most stores will cut the wire to your request. You can take an old used white from your box.

Comment: @crip659 I believe I lost it while unpacking the equipment a few weeks ago. Just now having the time to get around to it.

Comment: @Ruskes thanks for not insulting me. As far as using an old white wire, just wanted to confirm that this means I could essentially take one of the white wires that are all bundled together and capped off and use it for the switch?

Comment: Those white wires bundled together is the circuits neutrals, do not just remove one for the switch.  The switch's white/neutral wire is suppose to connect to them.  You need an extra piece of wire.  If lucky the other switch wires will have the gauge number printed on them, so you can get the right replacement.  As @Ruskes said most stores will sell small amount(or maybe even give) if ask nicely.  Will probably want 6 inches minimum.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I misunderstood.  NO..you can not do that. Each of the whites serves to complete the circuit, so you can not just disconnect. I know you want to test your new switch, and while no-one is looking you can temporally use any pice of wire (regardless of color), just to test. Please do not forget when you go to store to get the a piece of white wire.

Comment: Interesting how that drawing shows the white/neutral wires being wire nutted together, but the green/ground just magically joins in a "T".

Answer (score 5):

Common error is to think the bundle of neutrals is "spares" just lying there waiting for a smart switch.  Not at all, neutral is the normal return line, and those wires already have a job to do - return current for everything.  You'd need to add to the bundle - don't break it up.

### Beware the "big-box rut"

Three particular stores saturate every advertising channel: Home Depot, Lowes and Menards. All of them are "big box stores" following a particular consumer model: They use lies to convince you they're the only place to shop and you should ignore all other places or else you'll spend too much; and then they use Big Data computer analysis to rip you off.

I use 4-11/16" square steel boxes a lot. I pay $2-3. But if I walk into a big-box store pre-COVID, they were asking $6-7 for the same box with a straight face.  Why?  Because Big Data analysis of their customer service desk data showed **nobody ever price-checked** them on that box, and people keep buying it.

*Because*, they have forgotten where else to buy.

Likewise, they were able to quit selling wire by the foot, and stick you for small spools. **You have no other choice**.

### The other choices.

First, you have your friendly neighborhood locally owned **lumberyard**, which Home Depot etc. are doing their level best to put out of business. They sell building supplies and almost all of them have the rack of spools of wire for sales by-the-foot.

Then you have local **family-owned hardware stores** that Home Depot etc. don't as directly compete with.  Most of them also sell wire by-the-foot, mine just has a busted open 500' pack of Southwire 12/3 (same stuff Home Depot sells) and lets you buy per-foot at about 2x the 500' reel price.  Which is still fantastically better than a short spool price at Home Depot etc.

Finding these family-owned hardware stores is a bit confusing, because (to defend themselves) they formed *purchasing clubs* so they can buy at wholesale and handle distribution. These clubs are called **ACE** and **HWI/Do It Best**. They also let the store owners use the **ACE** or **Do It Best** logos on their storefronts.  But they are family-owned.

Third (this won't help with wire by-the-foot, but it's very useful for more serious stuff) is your local electrical supply house. You won't like them. They're located in boring industrial parks, not in pretty malls with huge parking lots.  But they have the best prices by far on electrical gear.

### What do you need exactly?

The ideal pigtail wire choice is 12 AWG solid THHN wire between 8 and 12 inches long.   My local "very boutiquey" overpriced family hardware store will trade me **a quarter** for a foot of that.

You can also buy 1 foot of 12/2 NM-B cable or 12/3 NM-B cable, and tear the sheath off it to get to the interior wires.

What I do is buy 2 feet of whichever wire, and then cut it into three 8" sections.  8" is just right for most pigtails.  But I use pigtails fairly regularly so I have uses for the remnants.

When buying pigtails, use #12 not #14 -- #12 is the universal donor usable on any circuit.  Using #14 is complicated.

#12 will not go into push-and-forget "backstabs" on the cheapest switches and receptacles, but using backstabs is a bad idea anyway as they have many failures.

Comment: @Ruskes  Where is the fun in that.  Harper gave the reasons for getting the right piece of wire and where and why.  Not everyone knows enough to go downstairs and hack off the right  piece of wire.

Answer (score 0):

For standard US/Canada residential wiring, the answer is going to be 14 AWG or 12 AWG if it is a 15A circuit (based on the breaker size) or 12 AWG if it is a 20A circuit.

You can do any of:

- Get some THHN 14 AWG (if 15A) or 12 AWG white wire. Use as is. Solid or stranded is OK, but probably easier to stick with solid to match your other wires.
- Get some non-metallic cable (Romex is the big name brand), either 14/2 (15A) or 12/2. Strip the outer sheath. Cut off a white wire and use it.

You can't use NM cable individual wires in conduit - i.e., for long runs between boxes. But inside an individual box you can.

As already noted, you need to connect the neutral for the switch to the bundle of neutrals. Remove the wire nut. Add the new wire. Twist well. (Possibly untwist the existing wires, add the new wire, twist all together.) Then twist on the wire nut.